# R/Tcltk conditional file menu command assignment

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to, given certain conditions are met, to change the command of a menu function after it is created. Given the code:

```
createMenu <- function(e) {
  topMenu <- tkmenu(e$wnd)
  tkconfigure(e$wnd, menu = topMenu)

  fileMenu <- tkmenu(topMenu, tearoff = FALSE)  # TOP menu
  tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Load ply File",command = function() loadPly(e))
  tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Save to DGT",command = function() saveToDgt(e))
  tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Load DGT File",command = function() openDgt(e))
  tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Exit", command = function() tkdestroy(e$wnd))
  tkadd(topMenu, "cascade", label = "File", menu = fileMenu)
}
```

Is there a way in R or tcltk to change the the utility of the command after it is initialized? I do not know how to grab the precise drop down menu option since it does not seem to be accessible.

Comment: Thre most certainly is a way (but I don't know how to say it in R). Menu entries can indeed be altered after creation. Not a good idea to do it while the menu is posted, of course...

Comment: @DonalFellows good news at least. How would it be done in regular tcltk?